# Mostrar un card en miniatrura cuando este en hover con JQUERY

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, card

Espero estén bien me podrían ayudar por favor!

Tengo unas cards  que contienen información de cada producto como podría que al hacer hover en la imagen aparezca esa misma card pero en miniatura en posicion fixed
he tratado de clonarla y mostrarla en otro div pero se duplica mas de una vez y tengo varias cards.

```
<html>
   <div class="card" id="card"  >
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="img/tres.jpg" alt="..." width="120px" class="imagenc" id="#tarjeta" >
</div>
      <p class="textd">TARJETA DE MEMORIA MICRO SD KINGSTON CLASE 10 (16 GB)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div id="copias"></div>
 <script>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>     
$("#tarjeta").hover(function() {
 $('#card:first').clone(true).appendTo('#copias');
  $('#copias').toggle();


});

 </script>
```

Comment: He intentado clonarlo y mostrarlo en otro div pero se clona mas de una vez